# Finding Edge Version for Webview2 WPF control in code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webview, microsoft-edge

I am trying to find Microsoft Edge version using the bellow C# code.

```
RegistryKey reg = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\PackageRepository\Packages");
        

if(reg != null)
{
    foreach(string subkey in reg.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        if(subkey.StartsWith("Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge"))
        {
            Match rxEdgeVersion = null;
            rxEdgeVersion = Regex.Match(subkey, @"(Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_)(?<version>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe)");
                       
            if (rxEdgeVersion.Success)
                return EdgeVersion = rxEdgeVersion.Groups["version"].Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function returns the version 44.18362.449.0.
But when i directly checking in Edge browser =>Settings=>help (edge://settings/help) version is Version 84.0.522.40

These two version patterns are not matching, also i have no parallel installation of different edge versions.

Please help me to relate both versions which are from browser UI and by C#.

Comment: Microsoft Edge's version number used to be 44, however with the release of the "new" version of Edge (in early 2020), Microsoft's Edge development team have decided to base a lot of the Edge Browser on the "Chromium" browser project.

Comment: did you already check the project's github issues? you are not alone :) https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebViewFeedback/issues/129

Comment: Thanks for the link. They are suggesting not to rely on registry entries :-).

Comment: they also mention `getcorewebview2browserversioninfo()` is it deprecated?

Comment: its not found , but still i need the installed  browser  version in client machine then only i can compare both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check the MS Edge Chromium browser version using C# code then I suggest try to check it on location below in the registry.

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{2CD8A007-E189-409D-A2C8-9AF4EF3C72AA}

If you check the value of the PV key then you can notice that it is showing the version of the Edge Chromium browser.

[image]

If you have other versions like Canary, beta, dev or stable then you can try to check the other folders in the Clients folder may help to get the version of the installed Edge Chromium browser.

Comment: Thanks:-)  Is this path same for both 64 & 32 bit machines ?

Comment: The path should be the same for both 32 and 64-bit machines.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application` there you'll likely find the new Chromium Edge with the correct version numbers as embedded in the file `msedge.exe` as well as in the folder name.

but why don't you check the browsers userAgent string? they have the version number included!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this aproach is depend on the installation folder .is ther any common method to detect whether edge chromium  latest version is installed ? .Path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application  is used even with legacyy edge ?. Actually i need the version number to detect if Microsoft Edge WebView2 will work in the machine .

Comment: the legacy Edge used that package approach, for the new Edge you may be right there is a custom install dir possible. See my edit in my answer.

Comment: i am not able to use user agent string because i am launching web view 2 in WPF application. So am checking if web view 2 got suitable edge version in the machine.

Comment: okay, I start to understand. your code won't even run without chromium edge installed as prereq?

Comment: Yes, my code need to load some HTML pages in latest browser if exists else i load pages in old IE engine.